Issue Uploading Media to Strapi API Using Postman: Receiving "Internal Server Error" Response
I am trying to upload media to the Strapi API using Postman. I have followed the documentation and ensured that the key field path is set with the value media.
However, every time I send the request, I keep getting the following response:
{
    "data": null,
    "error": {
        "status": 500,
        "name": "InternalServerError",
        "message": "Internal Server Error"
    }
}

I am using the POST method with the following configuration in Postman:
URL: http://url/images
Method: POST
Headers:
Authorization: Bearer <your_token_here>
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
Body:
Key: path
Type: File
Value: [the file I want to upload]

Despite this setup, I am still encountering the internal server error. Can anyone help me understand what might be going wrong? Thank you!
field
i was try
